# docker daemon doesn't start with systemd but will start interactively Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: systemd, docker

When I try to start my docker container, I get the following error message:

```
$ docker run ubuntu /bin/echo "Hello, World"
docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post THEN A URL v1.23/containers/create read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer.
See 'docker run --help'.
$
```

(The URL is http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock.  %2F is ASCII for / )
When I start the docker daemon interactively with the `docker daemon` command, it works fine, and the `docker run` command works fine.  However, if I try to start the daemon using systemd, then the daemon run command throws the error above.  I have done some creative googling and found several possible causes, however, I haven't found anything that addresses Ubuntu 16.04 and the articles I do find are very distribution specific.

```
$ docker info
Containers: 3
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 10
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-31-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.57 GiB
Name: jeff-desktop
ID: NCCP:GHRV:4ATV:SOA2:TMDZ:M6KV:726Z:MOF5:WHSA:I6ZQ:QPXI:7O7Q
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https: / / index . docker . io / v1 /
WARNING: No swap limit support


$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Thu, 16 Jun 2016 21:17:51 +1200
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Thu, 16 Jun 2016 21:17:51 +1200
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
$ uname -a
Linux jeff-desktop 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am very new to docker, so it would not surprise me at all if the problem is between the chair and the keyboard.